# Why can't I give items to friend in my party in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

My friend is about level 9 and I am 18. We are both playing on the same region and can join each others games fine.

However, I cannot give him items and he cannot give items to me - we don't see anything when anyone throws items to the ground and the trade button is greyed-out.

What's wrong?

Comment: when you say that you are both on euro I want to ask that question: are you in a same game? :D

Comment: If you have the "full" version and your friend has the "starter set" then you cannot trade or otherwise interact with each other. This is mainly to prevent some kind of abuses. For example you could make a dozen starter set accounts and put all your items on them. You would have unlimited storage space.

Comment: Great info about possible abuse. That explains some restrictions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It turned out you cannot trade items if an account is less than 72 hours old.

Comment: yup, but i can accept it only tomorrow :)